# How to get elements of one pandas dataframe based on the index from another in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that looks largely like the following:

```
y=numpy.random.uniform(0,1,10)

yx_index=[2,5,6,8]
yx=numpy.random.normal(0,1,4)
sety=pandas.DataFrame(y,columns=['set_y'])
subset_yx=pandas.DataFrame(yx,columns=['subset'],index=yx_index)
```

output:

```
set_y=

        set
0  0.548554
1  0.436084
2  0.192882
3  0.468712
4  0.290172
5  0.462640
6  0.072014
7  0.273997
8  0.242552
9  0.289873

set_x=

     set
2  0.943326
5  0.462640
6  2.433632
8  0.060528
```

`set_x` is always a subset of `set_y`. My question is, what is the easiest way to get elements of `set_y` which have indexes the same as `set_x`?

So in the above case the desired output would be:

```
set_z=

     set
2  0.192882
5  0.462640
6  0.072014
8  0.242552
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use one of many available [indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing). I would recommend `.ix[]` which is usually faster compared to `loc` / `iloc`:

```
In [86]: set_y.ix[set_x.index]
Out[86]:
        set
2  0.192882
5  0.462640
6  0.072014
8  0.242552
```

Comment: Nice and elegant. Thanks